# Random icon disappearance on taskbar when minimized

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar

I am developing an application with c# using WPF under vs2013.

When the application is minimized, the application icon disappears in the taskbar in a random manner (very rare occurrence, and seems happening more often when the system is slow). The application can only be restored by 'alt+tab' combination.

In the minimization key event handler, I added `ShowInTaskbar = true`, which does not help.

I list below the minimization handler.

The `WindowStyle` property of the main window is set to `None` in order to draw our custom "minimize", "maximize", and "close" buttons.

```
public void minimize_MouseDown()
{
    var main = ViewManager.GetInstance().main;
    main.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    main.ShowInTaskbar = true;            
}
```

Comment: Dear dymanoid, Sorry for my imprecision. Thank you!

Comment: Which Windows version do you use? Is there a Windows Zoom level set other than 100%?

Comment: Hello jHilscher, the same problem occurs under win7, win8.1. As for the Zoom level, I am not 100% certain, I think we left it as default which should be 100% when the problem occurs. @jHilscher